# Can I do PhD from different country after getting one PhD from one country?

Tags: phd, engineering

I am currently pursuing doctoral research in Chemical engineering department at IIT Kharagpur, India. I am about to complete my Ph.D. within 2 years. I am thinking of doing another Ph.D. possibly from outside India. But I would love to do a Ph.D. in the same area.

Comment: It can be done (depending on institutional rules), but why would you want to?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is doing two PhDs a good path?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/17232/is-doing-two-phds-a-good-path), https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/121066/second-phd-in-austria and other questions

Answer (score 1):

In general, yes, this is possible. More concretely, it depends on the rules of the institution your apply to (and on the people reading your application).
What you cannot do (at least in most reputable institutions) is to use the same research for two degrees.

However, do expect the question on why you want to do a second phd and prepare a good (and honest) answer.